# Application in android related to camera

Tags: android

In my camera application i have image-button,image-view and two button as confirm and save.On first display the image-button is visible and others are invisible, done the coding for how to get camera on by click of image button and also got image in image-view and on click of confirm button the save appear, but in this save on-click i want to save the image captured in image-view in a particular file on SD-card with serial naming loop as done in digital cam with ".PNG" extension.please help me .And thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

first you have to return bitmap from the image captured and then use this method on Button click i'm using it tho.

```
    void Save() {
    if (null != view.getDrawable()) {
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        view.buildDrawingCache();
        save = view.getDrawingCache();
        final File myDir = new File(folder);
        myDir.mkdirs();
        final Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        final String fname = "StyleMe-" + n + ".png";
          file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        try {
            final FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            save.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                    Uri.parse("file://"
                            + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Image Saved",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                    "Something Went Wrong check if you have Enough Memory",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        final Toast tst = Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                "Please Select An Image First", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        tst.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        tst.show();
    }
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
}
```

here i'm getting the image from the View as cashes and save it as `PNG` what you have to do is delete `if statement` and change save to your bitmap name  save.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);` 
and which it will be

```
    void Save() {
        final File myDir = new File(folder);
        myDir.mkdirs();
        final Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        final String fname = "StyleMe-" + n + ".png";
          file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        try {
            final FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            save.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); \\ change save to your Bitmap name 
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                    Uri.parse("file://"
                            + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Image Saved",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                    "Something Went Wrong check if you have Enough Memory",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

}
```

`
and here is my folder string

```
    String folder = "/sdcard/Pictures/StyleMe";
```

and my `static File file;`
 and P.S this method it will automatically tell the Gallery to scan for new files , without restarting the phone or doing it manually . do accept the answer if that what you seek for and vote it for sure.
Edit: add this in your manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: hey i appreciate for your active help but one problem do come don't know why i am using this code on emulator and have set SD-card also but still arises the toast msg u have written in catch statement

Comment: i guess because the method is not getting the sdCard from the emulator. try to install it on your phone it sure it will work. P.S i'm using this method on my application and it works perfectly , i never tried it on emulator before xD i test all my apps on my phones :D

Comment: mail ur emailid i will email u my code as iam unable to post this as word limit